# Equivalent of __FILE__?

Tags: import, evaluation, files-and-directories, system-variables

Many languages define a special identifier whose value is the path to the source file currently being processed.  (For example, in C, this is done through the `__FILE__` preprocessor macro.)

Does Mathematica have anything like this (at least for `*.m` files)?

(I could not find a tag that adequately represents the topic of this question (namely, something like "source file processing"); suggestions welcome.)

Comment: What about \$InputFileName and \$Input?

Comment: @bobknight, `$InputFileName` fits the bill.  I'll gladly accept it if you post it as an Answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to get an answer on record.

As bobknight stated in the comments [`$InputFileName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24InputFileName.html) is bound to a string giving the full path name of the file being read when code loading operations initiated by `Get`, (`<<`), or `Needs` are in the process of loading. The file being loaded can make use this information, but the notebook requesting the load cannot (think of it as if `$InputFileName` were bound to the path-name inside a `Block`, which may actually be the case).

[`$Input`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24Input.html) is a system variable that works similarly to `$InputFileName` but only gives the file name.

#### Correction

`$Input`is a system variable that works similarly to `$InputFileName`, but is bound to name of the stream from which the loading file is being read. See my [additional answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29149/3066) for more detail.

Comment: For completeness: in version 7, `$InputFileName` is undocumented and located in `System\`Private\`` context.

Answer (score 2):

Some additional details on `$Input`. The *Mathematica* documentation states that `$Input` is bound to the name of the stream from which the loading file is being read. But what is that stream name? It appears to be whatever string `Get`, (`<<`), or `Needs` receive as their first argument.

To test this hypothesis, I made a .m file with the following contents and placed in on my system's desktop.

---

```
Print[Streams[]]
Print[Row[{"$Input: ", $Input}]]
Print[Row[{"$InputFileNamw: ", $InputFileName}]]
```

---

I then evaluated the following expressions from an open notebook:

```
Get[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen", "*.m"]]
```

> {OutputStream[stdout, 1], OutputStream[stderr, 2], InputStream[/Users/oldmg/Desktop/TestPkg.m, 86]}
>   \$Input: /Users/oldmg/Desktop/TestPkg.m
>   \$InputFileName: /Users/oldmg/Desktop/TestPkg.m

```
SetDirectory[FileNameJoin[{HomeDirectory[], "Desktop"}]];
Get["TestPkg.m"]
```

> {OutputStream[stdout, 1], OutputStream[stderr, 2], InputStream[TestPkg.m, 118]}
>   \$Input: TestPkg.m
>   \$InputFileName: /Users/oldmg/Desktop/TestPkg.m

Note in the first case, `$Input` and `$InputFileName` are bound to the same string. This is because `SystemDialogInput` returns a full path name. In the second case, however,  `$Input` is bound to a string giving only the file name because that is all that was passed to it.